# Back propagation equation proof

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am trying to prove this equation (from the backpropagation equations in AI).

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j^l} = \delta_j^l$$

C is the cost function: $C = \frac{1}{2}||y - a^L||^2$

Where the output of layer *l* and neuron *j* is express like so $a^l_j=σ(∑_kw^l_{jk}a^{l−1}_k+b^l_j)$

I am suppose to use this assertion to do the demonstration: $\delta_j^L = \frac{\partial C}{\partial z_j^L}$

So far, here is what I have tried:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_j^L} = \sum_k \frac{\partial C}{\partial z_j^L} \frac{\partial b_j^l}{\partial b_j^L} $$  (I am using the *chain rule* to have a sum)

<=>     $$\frac{\partial C}{\partial z_j^L} = \sum_k \frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j^l} \frac{\partial b_j^l}{\partial z_j^L} $$

So I guess I have to prove, that $\frac{\partial b_j^l}{\partial z_j^L}$ equals 1.

But I don't have any ideas how to prove it.

Thanks for your help

**N.B**
I am following this course => http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html where the first two equations of the BackPropagation equations are already proved, and the 2 others should be proved the same way (using the *chain rule*)

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $$  \frac{\partial C}{\partial z_j^\ell} = \delta_j^\ell  $$ $$ z^\ell_k = \sum_i w_{ki}^\ell a^{\ell -1}_j + b_k^{\ell} $$
the latter of which means that
$$ \frac{\partial z^\ell_k}{\partial b_\alpha^\ell} = \Delta^\ell_{k\alpha}=\begin{cases} 
1 & \text{if } k=\alpha \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
We want to show that
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j^\ell} = \delta_j^\ell $$
Since $C$ depends on $b_\beta$ through $z^\beta$, we can use the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial b_j^\ell} 
&= \sum_\zeta \frac{\partial C}{\partial z_\zeta^\ell}  \frac{\partial z_\zeta^\ell}{\partial b_j^\ell} \\
&= \sum_\zeta \delta^\ell_\zeta  \Delta^\ell_{\zeta j} \\
&= \delta^\ell_j
\end{align}
where the Kronecker delta $\Delta_{\zeta j}^\ell$ collapses out the sum except for the $j$th term.